# Neo4j with MemSQL

Tags: database, search, neo4j, tree, cypher

We are building software using Neo4j as a graph for searching through A LOT of filters and then using the results to populate a query we can use in MemSQL to return all results based on the search results.

I'm just wondering if this is a possible use case before we make a start and discover Neo4j isn't used for that? The Neo4j documentation is pretty poor.

Thanks all!

Comment: What exactly are you missing in the Neo4j docs. Only "filters" doesn't sound like a graph database use-case, rather RDBMS. Perhaps you can share some of your model and what questions you want to ask the database.

Comment: Essentially we have around 12 filters that initially need to show all the data available and these can be selected individually with different values and the rest of the filters would then need to be updated with the related data. E.g. if A is selected then return all instances of B, C and D related to A but ignore the rest.